# Finding the first occurrence of a regex match using match.index

Tags: regex, vb.net

How do I access the .index method in regex, so in this case it should output the location of the first instance of a number

```
    Dim sourceString As String = "abcdefg12345"
    Dim textboxregex As Regex = New Regex("^(d)$")

    If textboxregex.IsMatch(sourceString) Then
        Console.WriteLine(Match.Index) 'this should display the location of the first occurrence of the pattern within the sourcestring
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you dont need regex:

```
Dim digits = From chr In sourceString Where Char.IsDigit(chr)
Dim index = -1
If digits.Any() Then index = sourceString.IndexOf(digits.First())
```

or in one statement with the ugly method syntax:

```
Dim index As Int32 = "abcdefg12345".
    Select(Function(chr, ix) New With {chr, ix}).
    Where(Function(x) Char.IsDigit(x.chr)).
    Select(Function(x) x.ix).
    DefaultIfEmpty(-1).
    First()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a Lookbehind:

```
Dim textboxregex As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\D)\d")
If textboxregex.IsMatch(sourceString) Then
    Console.WriteLine(textboxregex.Match(sourceString).Index)
End If
```

This will match the first occurence of a digit after all non digit characters.

Comment: Removed the escapes of a backslash... im more used to c# where you have to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex expression is wrong (you need the '\' before the d) and you haven't defined Match

```
Dim sourceString As String = "abcdefg12345"
Dim textboxregex As Regex = New Regex("\d")
Dim rxMatch as Match = textboxregex.Match(sourceString)

If rxMatch.success Then
    Console.WriteLine(rxMatch.Index) 'this should display the location of the first occurrence of the pattern within the sourcestring
End If
```